# How to turn rows into columns in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

How can I achieve this using SQL Server?

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: You should read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
You should also probably search this site before asking your question since this question has likely been asked (and answered) many, many times before.

Comment: Look into pivoting questions in SQL server tag for answers and examples.

Answer (score -1):

Using [PIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) is what you need.
Plenty of examples on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pivot%20sql-server)

To replicate the expected answer in the OP

```
DECLARE @tab TABLE (ID INT, CODE INT, ECODE VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @tab
(ID, CODE, ECODE)
VALUES
(1, 101, 'error1'),
(1, 102, 'error2'),
(1, 103, 'error3'),
(1, 104, 'success'),
(2, 101, 'error1'),
(2, 102, 'error2'),
(2, 103, 'error3'),
(2, 104, 'success')


SELECT
      T.ID
    , MAX(CASE WHEN T.CODE = 101 THEN T.CODE END) 'CODE1'
    , MAX(CASE WHEN T.ECODE = 'error1' THEN T.ECODE END) 'ECODE1'
    , MAX(CASE WHEN T.CODE = 102 THEN T.CODE END) 'CODE2'
    , MAX(CASE WHEN T.ECODE = 'error2' THEN T.ECODE END) 'ECODE2'
    , MAX(CASE WHEN T.CODE = 103 THEN T.CODE END) 'CODE3'
    , MAX(CASE WHEN T.ECODE = 'error3' THEN T.ECODE END) 'ECODE3'
    , MAX(CASE WHEN T.CODE = 104 THEN T.CODE END) 'CODE4'
    , MAX(CASE WHEN T.ECODE = 'Success' THEN T.ECODE END) 'ECODE4'
FROM @tab T
GROUP BY T.ID
```

Comment: I cant get that output of rows into alternate columns? can anyone please help with the answer

Comment: Are the `CODE`s always going to be 101, 102, 103,104? Will these always be groups of 4 per `ID`